# Career's feature request: multiple cover letters

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I do understand that each and every cover letter should be tailored to the specific position (even within the same company) we are applying for, but...

If one's skills span across several fields (from PHP programming to artificial intelligence, for example), one may want to apply for jobs that are related either to one or another - sicne it's very hard to find an employer that seeks a PHP expert in AI -

Anyway, since the cover letters for different positions are always similar, in the means that they tend to highlight certain aspects of our profile, I'd like to propose to store multiple cover letters (let's say up to 3) as templates in Careers, so we can recall **and edit** them easily.

Example:

> Candidate: worked 2002-2007 on PHP, 2007-2009 on Python/MongoDB
>
> Cover letter 1 fragment: "...In fact, I have extensive experience in PHP development..."
>
> Cover letter 2 fragment: "...Not to mention that I am very knowledgeable to NoSQL..."

And so on...

It would be nice to have two or three "template" letters and start from them rather than from the very last sent.

Comment: I agree this would be useful as most postings will fall some more general category.